# validation data before insert them into the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, validation, triggers

I know how to validate data using Client Side (`JAVASCRIPT`) , Server Side (`PHP`) and Database(`Triggers in mysql`).Do i want to validate data in all these methods when working with a large application process ? if i used those methods to validate does it slow ? if it's what is the fasted way  to do it ?

**JAVASCIPT**

```
var data $("#input").val();

if(is_nan(data)){

}
```

**PHP**

```
if(empty($_POST['input'])){

}
```

**MYSQL**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON registrations FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.RG_Reg_NO NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z]{3}\/[A-Z]-\d{6}$' THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The registration number you have entered is wrong';
END IF;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Javascript. Why a second call to a serverscript, ultimately a call to the database? Much better to catch up clientside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's my approach & opinions:

#### Client side validation is always needed for two reasons:

- better user exprience
- avoid round trips to the server and reduce payload (That is the main reason why Netscape came up with javascript in the first place).

#### Server side validation is always needed for two reasons:

- **security!** as someone can always post requests(curl) and bypass your client side validation.
- provide fallback to js disabled clients (very rare nowadays).

#### Database validation:

- If you have to avoid mistakes by the team that writes the server side code use those.
- If your team is small and the one who writes the server side code is able to implement all the business logic without double checking it at another level than don't use those.
- If you prefer productivity and flexibility over data integrity don't use those.
- If you don't have someone at your team that really knows how to deal with sql spaghetti then don't use those!!
- If your application is so large that performance starts to be an issue then you must first check out NOSQL solutions if they feet your requirements before entering the SQL spaghetti maze. Also employ an experienced dba.

**Feel free to add more reasons or to correct my mistakes.**

Answer (score 0):

This is subjective - how secure do you need to be and how confident are you in writing secure code?

I would personally use client side first (to save on over-head on server more than anything) then php check (for site safety) before doing prepared INSERTS, UPDATES or DELETES etc.

However if you think there is scope for someone to run queries on your database then the MySQL check could be used

Overheads are quite small for all so it depends on acceptable script times, number of users etc.

Like I said subjective - I would go javascript php and make sure my code is secure but thats just me.

**NEVER** just javascript checks - way to easy for me to start calling functions and ruining your database.

Answer (score 0):

Usually validation on client side (javascript) and serverside (php) would be sufficient .
Because if someone has js disabled, then your js validation will not take place. Therefore you would rely on php for validation.